# Why my server socket hangs on reading the body of http post request?

Tags: java, sockets, http, post, inputstream

**Warning:** This is a self answered question. I faced this problem recently and found it very tricky, though it sounds very simple. I decided to post a complete question and answer with code examples for future visitors.

---

I have a ServerSocket, that listens connection on port 12005. It is implemented in the simpliest way:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(12005);
while(true) {
    executorService.submit(new SocketProcessor(ss.accept());
}
```

Here `SocketProcessor` is just a `Runnable`, that handles incoming connections:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
       String msg = IOUtils.toString(s.getInputStream());
       // process msg here
    } finally {
        s.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is that execution hangs on `IOUtils.toString(InputStream is)` method. I thought that standard solution will work better, so I replaced it with

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

The output was something like:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: http://localhost:12005
Content-Type: application/json
//other headers
                  <--- empty line
                  <--- here it hangs
```

If I abort the connection on the caller side, I can see a new line in output - actually it is http body:

```
{"name":"alex", "hobby":"football"}
```

I tried two different request sender implementations and they both hung when I tried to read http body. That means the problem is exactly in my server socket.
 What is wrong with this implementation from tutorials?

Answer (score 2):

I was lucky to find the explanation on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjava/comments/3gp3bs/socket_reading_http_request_not_the_apache_library/) forum.

In short, the structure of http post message is the following

```
start-line CRLF 
header-field-1 CRLF
header-field-2 CRLF
header-field-N CRLF
CRLF  
message-body
```

As you can see there is no new-line symbol after message body. Because of this `readLine()` method does not work as we expected. I guess Apache `IOUtils.toString()` method faces the same problem. To fix the problem, the following solution is suggested:

1. find Content-Length header and read its value N
2. read exact N bytes after header section is over

Here's the sample code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
boolean headersFinished = false;
int contentLength = -1;

while (!headersFinished) {
     String line = br.readLine();
     headersFinished = line.isEmpty();

     if (line.startsWith("Content-Length:")) {
         String cl = line.substring("Content-Length:".length()).trim();
         contentLength = Integer.parseInt(cl);
     }
}

// validate contentLength value
char[] buf = new char[contentLength];  //<-- http body is here
br.read(buf);
```

Comment: There is a `CRLF` at the end of `start-line`. Not all request methods have a `message-body` (most notably `GET` and `HEAD`). And for those that do, HTTP 1.1 servers must support `chunked` requests, which do not use a `Content-Length` header to indicate where the end of the `message-body` is located.

Comment: The problem is in *your* implementation off HTTP that doesn't conform to RFC 2616. Nothing to do with 'socket implementation'.

Comment: @EJP what's the point of referring to this question with C code? When I googled 'http post hangs/http body/socket', I did not find that answer.

Comment: The point is that you weren't implementing Content-length, regardless of which language.